# get instances of class interface implementations in a file PHP

Tags: php, plugins, reflection, interface

Lets say I have file myplugin.php

How can I get a list of all the classes that implement a certain interface?

Real simple

Answer (score 2):

1. Load all files (you could have a plugins directory for example)
2. Iterate through the get_declared_classes() result
3. Check for the implementation: class_implements()

Comment: or grep -r "implements $classname" * :)

Comment: Nice solution! :) But it has a hard dependency on grep and sometimes a concrate implementation derives from an abstract one so we would have to maintain class hierarchy.

Comment: Just abstract out a file system searcher which has grep as it's sole concrete implementation then inject it into your dependency figure outer. That should appease the IoC gods